# TypeScript error: Type '() => boolean' is not assignable to type 'boolean'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

If array of `user_list.length == 0`, the "clear user" button should be disabled. When I am calling `this.disabledButton` function, it throws an error saying

> Type '() => boolean' is not assignable to type 'boolean'

Below is my logic.

```
<section>
     <Button
        id='clear-user'
        disabled={this.disabledButton}
        onClick={this.onClearAllUserButton}>
        {'Clear User List'}
     </Button>
</section>
```

Function defined:

```
 private disabledButton= (): boolean => {
    if (this.props.user_list.length == 0) {
      return true
    }
    return false
  }
```

Is my calling wrong?

Comment: `disabled` prop accepts a boolean value, `disabledButton` is a function that returns a boolean value. A function is not assignable to a boolean.

Comment: A _function returning_ a boolean is not assignable to a boolean. Seems logical. Perhaps the function was to be _invoked_ such that the _result_ could be assigned..

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You're passing a function that returns a boolean (type `() => boolean`) to a property that expects a boolean (type `boolean`). You just have to actually execute your function.

```
disabled={this.disabledButton()}
```

This error message tells you everything:

```
"Type '() => boolean' is not assignable to type 'boolean'"
```

`() => boolean` is the function you are trying to assign, and `boolean` is the type it's expecting. It's up to you to notice what those two types are and figure out how to make them match.